# Error unwrapping UITableView cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I know I am force unwrapping a nil but I dont know how to fix it.

I am just trying to follow a tutorial and can't get help from the author. I am getting this error:

> "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "firstcell")
    cell?.textLabel?.text = firstTableArrary[indexPath.row]
    return cell!
```

Comment: Which line is the error on?  Are you sure your tableview has registered a cell with a reuseIdentifier called "firstcell"?  Also, I always check to make sure my array is big enough to support the given indexPath.  Like `guard firstTableArray.count > indexPath.row else { return cell }`

Comment: Are you sure that `dequeueReusableCell` shouldn't also have a `for` parameter?

Comment: @48Straight are you registering cell in viewDidLoad(), and also from storyboard??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you registered the cell's identifier in the storyboard or programmatically? If you did, check the spelling (case sensitive) of the reuse identifier.

Comment: `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)` doesn't use a registered cell.

Comment: @rmaddy You should go read the basics at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614891-dequeuereusablecell before commenting or downvoting.

Comment: I thought only `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)` used a registered cell. I've been using `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)` for nearly a decade and didn't notice that it can also use a registered cell. But clearly, in the OP's code, `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)` is returning `nil`. You should expand your answer to provide more details. Your "answer" is really nothing more than a comment.

Comment: Nailed it. After all those hours of research it was a spelling error LOL. THANK YOU!!!!!

Comment: @rmaddy `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)` will only deque a cell registered in the storyboard or xib or in the code using tableview's `register(_:forCellReuseIdentifier:)` or a cell which is initialized using  `init(style:reuseIdentifier:)`. Otherwise it returns `nil`. Hence I asked to check if the cell is registered or not. Not sure how you have been using it for a "decade" yet you never happened to notice this. Or do you use magic to auto map the cell with the a random string as its identifier? Try setting aside your ego and contributing more than showing off your "decade" worth xp

Comment: When I use `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)` I never register a cell. Instead, I check if `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)` returns `nil`. If it does, I then create the cell with the proper initializer. This approach has existed since iOS 2.0. The ability to register a cell didn't get added until iOS 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

I changed this line of code:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "firstcell")
```

to this:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "firstcell",  for: indexPath)
```

then all set! I don't have an optional cell to unwrap. I don't know why. But it works.